# Why is there no output when using a PHP list function?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to assign values of pathinfo function to variables like so:

```
list($dirname, $basename, $extension, $filename) = pathinfo($path_image);
echo $dirname.$basename.$extension.$filename;
```

However there is no output.

**But if I run only:**

```
print_r(pathinfo($path_image));
```

I get output like so:

```
Array ( [dirname] => http://blah.com/images [basename] => image123.jpg [extension] => jpg [filename] => image123)
```

Comment: Comment number 2 here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: Put error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); at the top of your script and let us know what errors are you seeing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Work:**

```
list($dirname, $basename, $extension, $filename) = array_values(pathinfo($wallpaper_image));
echo $dirname.$basename.$extension.$filename;
```

Answer (score 5):

1. `list()` is not a function, it is a language construction.
2. It does not work with associative arrays. It works with indexed ones.

***From [php.net](http://php.net/list):***

> this is not really a function, but a language construct

---

> list() only works on numerical arrays and assumes the numerical
>   indices start at 0.

---

To fix that, you may try to ommit result array keys by [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array-values), as mentiononed in answer of **@anupam**:

```
<?php
$values = array_values(pathinfo($path_image));
list($dirname, $basename, $extension, $filename) = $values;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

pathinfo() returns an associative array. So, your code should work as follows:

```
list($dirname, $basename, $extension, $filename) = array_values(pathinfo($path_image));
```